# WooCommerce allowing html syntax in category description field

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, categories

I'm using a themeforest theme for my new WooCommerce store. 
While I go to edit *category* there's a *description field* which doesn't allow *html tags*.

**My question:** How can I make this field accepting html tags?

So I can put a banner image and centralize text etc… 
**I do not want to use any plugin** as there are already available.

What would I need to do to enable text editor inside description field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`wp_filter_kses()` function filters the description in WP / WC categories. So what you need is disabling that filter.

You will need to add this code to your function.php file (located in your active theme folder):

```
foreach ( array( 'pre_term_description' ) as $filter ) { 
    remove_filter( $filter, 'wp_filter_kses' ); 
} 
foreach ( array( 'term_description' ) as $filter ) { 
    remove_filter( $filter, 'wp_kses_data' ); 
}
```

You can't enable (and don't need) the rich text editor in that description category field, but after adding the code above, you will be able to add html effective tags *(like a banner image or other html tags…)*

**Advice:** Is better to enable a chid theme (based on your active theme), then when adding code to the funcion.php file of your child theme, you will not lose anything, when the theme get updated…

This post is related to: [*Wordpress* Category Descriptions - HTML?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/98034/category-descriptions-html)

Comment: Hi LoicTheAztec. Thank you so much for your help. I'll try it.. Thanks again

Comment: Hi LoicTheAztec. Thank you so much for your help. I applied the coe and it really worked. Thanks once again..

Comment: https://woocommerce.com/document/allow-html-in-term-category-tag-descriptions/